# Virtual Host not serving up correct website with same IP address

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost

I've got two virtual hosts running on the same server (IP address: 123.123.123.123):

VirtualHost 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 123.123.123.123

    DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/user/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/logfiles/error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/logfiles/access_log" common
    <Directory "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/user/htdocs/">
            AllowOverride   All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And VirtualHost 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName temp.co.uk

    DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/development/temp"
    ErrorLog "/home/webmaster/development/temp/error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/webmaster/development/temp/access_log" common
    <Directory "/home/webmaster/development/temp">
            AllowOverride   All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to www.temp.co.uk it show the "temp" website (which is what I want), however when I want to the "myNEWsite" by going to `http://123.123.123.123/` it still shows the "temp" site.

How do I get the actual IP address of my server to show the new site I'm building?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a virtual network interface](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux) and add another IP to the second virtual host / server name:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myNEWsite

    DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/user/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/logfiles/error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/logfiles/access_log" common
    <Directory "/home/webmaster/development/myNEWsite.co.uk/user/htdocs/">
            AllowOverride   All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and ...

```
<VirtualHost <virtual interface IP>:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName temp.co.uk

    DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/development/temp"
    ErrorLog "/home/webmaster/development/temp/error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/webmaster/development/temp/access_log" common
    <Directory "/home/webmaster/development/temp">
            AllowOverride   All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Check [this site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) for more on virtual host configuration.

**p.s.**: added some hints about virtual network devices.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I forgot to mention, these virtual hosts are all on the same server with the ip address: 123.123.123.123

Comment: That sounds tricky :) you can have the same IP for both server names and define the names inside the tag. This way you can access the different sites by name. Ok, you knew this probably already ;) so the only solution I see is: set up another virtual network interface for your device and use two different IPs for the server names. It's quite easily done. Check for instance http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux on this topic.